# Code doesn't detect file is open

Tags: c#, asp.net, filestream

I have an ASP.Net 4.5 web application. One of the pages writes a file to the file system when a button is clicked. This file is also accessed by another process, a third-party program I have no control over. This other program reads the file and then moves it to a subfolder. Because of this, I'm creating a `FileStream` using the Append `FileMode`: it creates the file if it doesn't exist, or appends to it if it does. I want to make sure in my application, when the button is clicked, that this third-party app isn't accessing the file. I've written the following code (which I cribbed [from here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4920703a-4552-49f9-8eb9-28b12c58e5f6/how-do-i-check-if-file-is-in-usebusy-before-continue-the-rest-of-the-code-?forum=csharpgeneral)), but when I test it, it doesn't detect that the file is open. When I say the file is open, I mean that during testing I open the file in Notepad. I'm doing this work on a Windows 7 machine using Visual Studio 2012, if that matters. Why doesn't it see that the file is open?

```
bool TryOpen(string FileWithPath, out FileStream fs)
    {
        try
        {
            fs = File.Open(FileWithPath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            fs = null;
            return false;
        }
    }

    FileStream OpenASAP(string path, int maxTries)
    {
        FileStream fs = null;
        bool lastResult = false;
        int count = 0;
        while ((lastResult = !TryOpen(path, out fs)) && count < maxTries)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            count++;
        }
        if (!lastResult || count >= maxTries)
        {
        }
        return fs;
    }

protected void writeToClientFile(DataSet ClientGenl, DataSet ClientBus, DataSet ClientBill)
    {
        FileStream fileStream = null;
        string fileName = "ClientTest.txt";
         string pathName = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["EliteFilePath"].ToString();
            try
        {
            using (new KLClassLibrary.Impersonator(proxyaccount, domain, password))
            {
fileStream = OpenASAP(pathName + fileName, 3);
etc.....
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a perfect job for a FileSystemWatcher. Do you also write in this one file? Is that the problem? If so, write to a temp file and when done writing rename to file that will get moved

Comment: A little more information on the overall workflow of the 2 apps could be helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test is faulty. Windows `notepad` application does not lock the file, it reads the content into memory and immediately releases the file handle.

Use a different application that you know to keep a lock on the file *or* write a dummy console that opens the file using a `FileStream` and releases it after you press a button, example:

```
using (var f = File.Open(@"c:\some-path\some-name.ext", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
{
    Console.WriteLine("File locked. Press ENTER to continue");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Works beautifully. Thank you so much!